# How to switch object in sculpt mode?

Tags: modeling, sculpting

I've search it in the internet. Some of the answer said you can use alt + left mouse to do so. But mine dosen't work... I wonder whether is beacuse I changed my hotkey to left select and some action to alt+ mouse click action or not.
If so , how do I get it back while not changing my own hotkey setting. Or what is the name of that alt + left mouse action call in keymap so I can change it to other hotkeys.
Thank you

Answer (score 8):

In Blender 3.0 and above, you can hover over objects and press <kbd>Alt</kbd> +  <kbd>Q</kbd> to switch to another object while you are in sculpt mode.

Answer (score 2):

Go to the Edit menu, untick the box next to 'Lock Object Modes' so it is off.

This will allow switching to another object (and whatever mode its in). So, you'll have to switch the other objects mode to Sculpt. Once the objects individual modes are set to sculpt, you can switch between them and still be in sculpt mode.

I think the hotkey name is "view3d.select" you can search for it by name in the keymap editor.

Answer (score 2):

From Blender 2.93 you can hover your mouse over the other object while in sculpt mode and press <kbd>D</kbd>.

Answer (score 1):

I have another way to select objects in sculpt mode convenient for those who use tablets. Select objects in your Scene Collection (hope you name it before).

Comment: In Blender 2.93, the key D switches between objects in Sculpt mode now.

Comment: So true xd Thanx)

Answer (score 0):

In blender 3.0 the <kbd>D</kbd> key seems not to work. So I managed to achieve almost the same behavior defining a customized keymap:

- Enter in preferences, under keymap look for *3DView > Sculpt > Sculpt (Global)*
- Define 2 actions as follow

[image: uiactions]

The first action to set is `view3d.select`, flag the Object checkbox, set D as shortcut

the second action to set is `bpy.ops.object.mode_set(mode='SCULPT')`, and even for this action set the <kbd>D</kbd> key as shortcut

I said "almost" because it seems you have to enter in sculpt mode at least one time manually before getting the switch to work afterwards

Comment: I just found another method, in sculpt mode clicking on another object by holding ALT key it will allow you to switch directly to the sculpt mode of that object, and if there are more than one in line a menu appears to let you choose the correct one. I suppose this is the native and best solution.

Answer (score -1):

You need to go to *Object Mode*, then switch and come back into *Sculpt Mode*.

Comment: haha, I know that , I just thought maybe there is a quicker way to do that. Thank you though

Comment: dont be mean , work hard , haa , no offence